# I am asked to update a xml file using python but I am stucked in using a if condition there

Tags: python, xml, conditional-statements

Given below is the xml content I am given with

```
<motorvehicles>
    <vehicle>
        <registration_no>CBB1456</registration_no>
        <make>Toyota</make>
        <model>Premio</model>
    </vehicle>
    <vehicle>
        <registration_no>PR2245</registration_no>
        <make>Mazda</make>
        <model>Bongo</model>
    </vehicle>
    <vehicle>
        <registration_no>DE2115</registration_no>
        <make>TATA</make>
        <model>Sumo</model>
    </vehicle>
    <vehicle>
        <registration_no>Car7785</registration_no>
        <make>Kia</make>
        <model>Optimas</model>
    </vehicle>
</motorvehicles>
```

And I am asked to modify the details of the vehicle with registration_no "DE2115" as below..

```
<registration_no>DE2115</registration_no>
 <make>Nissan</make>
 <model>Skyline</model>
```

And to finally print the the Registration Numbers of each Nissan vehicle.

Below is my own answer

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
vehicle_xml_data_as_string = "<motorvehicles><vehicle><registration_no>CBB1456</registration_no><make>Toyota</make><model>Premio</model></vehicle><vehicle><registration_no>PR2245</registration_no><make>Mazda</make><model>Bongo</model></vehicle><vehicle><registration_no>DE2115</registration_no><make>TATA</make><model>Sumo</model></vehicle><vehicle><registration_no>CAR7785</registration_no><make>Kia</make><model>Optima</model></vehicle></motorvehicles>"
root=ET.fromstring(vehicle_xml_data_as_string)

for registration_no in root.iter('registration_no'):
    if registration_no.text=="DE2115":
        for element in root.iter(tag="make"):
            newmake="Nissan"
            element.text=newmake
        for element in root.iter(tag="model"):
            newmodel="Skyline"
            element.text=newmodel
            
for element in root.iter('make'):
    if element.text=="Nissan":
        for element in root.iter('vehicle'):
            regno=element.find('registration_no').text
            print(regno)
```

Answer I am supposed get is DE2115
But I am getting all registration numbers instead.Kindly help me with this..i am not much comfortable with xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you call `root.iter` it iterates through every element in the tree, each time. so the code block below changes all of the `make` tags to nissan, not just the one that is under the registration number `"DE2115"`.

```
if registration_no.text=="DE2115":
    for element in root.iter(tag="make"):
        newmake="Nissan"
        element.text=newmake
```

Instead you should iterate through each vehicle and check the values of each of the children of the vehicle.

For example:

```
for element in root.iter('vehicle'):
    regno = element.find("registration_no")
    if regno.text == "DE2115":
        make = element.find("make")
        make.text = "Nissan"
        model = element.find("model")
        model.text ="Skyline"

for element in root.iter('vehicle'):
    if element.find("make").text == "Nissan":
        regno = element.find('registration_no').text
        print(regno)
```

OUTPUT

```
DE2115
```

Comment: Thank you...It worked..but can you pls explain me further the difference between using element and vehicle in for loop..i mean in the second for loop you used for elemnet in root.iter() while in the first for loop you used for vehicle in root.iter()..What is the purpose of changing vehicle in to element in the second loop...Please kindly explain me how they work..

Comment: there is no reason... that is just the name of the variable... it makes no difference what the name is.  I will change it to be more consistent @kavi_02  I changed it so that they are both say element, but changing them so they both said vehicle would be the same..  I could make one of the named pancake and the other named leprosy and it wouldn't matter, variable names are just placeholders and can be named whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

One problem looks to be in this block.

```py
for registration_no in root.iter('registration_no'):
    if registration_no.text=="DE2115":
        for element in root.iter(tag="make"):
            newmake="Nissan"
            element.text=newmake
        for element in root.iter(tag="model"):
            newmodel="Skyline"
            element.text=newmodel
```

I think after you find the correct `registration_no`, you are then iterating over everything

```py
if registration_no.text=="DE2115":
    for element in root.iter(tag="make"):
```

setting all `'make'`s to be `'Nissan'`
simmilarly with the `model` elements